# How does "sell out" work? How to understand it?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, transitivity, active-vs-passive

I find the phrasal verb "sell out" a bit confusing.

Which is/are wrong?

1. We're sold out.
2. We're sold out of X.
3. We sold out.
4. We sold out of Y.
5. Tickets have sold out.
6. Tickets have been sold out.

Does "we sold out of X" means "X, the thing we sell, sold out" and "we are sold out"?

Comment: Good question. As David Siegel says in his answer, all these work: it can refer to the goods or the sellers, and can be active or stative. Not surprised you are confused!

Answer (score 2):

"to sell out" in general means that everything available for sale ahs been sold, so that not is left available for sale.

"We sold out of X" means that all of X was sold, and none is left. "We are sold out" means that we have sold everything we have for sale, unless a previous sentence restricts the meaning to a particular item or group of items. For example:

> We did a good business on  burgers, we're sold out.

means that they are sold out of burgers, but perhaps not of other things.

Examples 1, 2, 3, and 4 in the question are clearly correct and need no changes. I would add "the" to 5 and 6. giving "The tickets have sold out."

6a "The tickets have been sold out." has a somewhat different meaning, and suggests that the tickets have been in a sold-out state for some time. I would mostly prefer 5, or rather 5A above.